# Is there a way to elemenate a subquery from this Hive query?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Edit: I am using `Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152)`

When I run the following query:

`insert into delta_table (select * from batch_table where loaddate=(select max(loaddate) from batch_table));`

I get this error:

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'loaddate': Only SubQuery expressions
>   that are top level conjuncts are allowed

We have a table that is written to in daily batches with the column `loaddate` that is unique for each batch. The purpose of the query is to get all the records from the most recent batch without knowing what it's load date is.
I suspect the issue is because I am using a subquery inside a subquery. Is there a way to change this query to do the same thing, but without the last subquery?

Comment: depend on which version of hive you have ?  , you can use the clause ( with as )

Comment: Replace that with a derived table and join to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error was because the table was created incorrectly and for some reason this caused the query to fail. I recreated the table and it now works

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which version of hive you have , but you can use the Clause with to avoid the second subquery

```
with max_load as ( select max(loaddate) as loaddate from batch_table) 
    insert into delta_table 
    (select * from batch_table a where a.loaddate=max_load.loaddate);
```

Comment: I have `Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152)`, I tried that query, but got a `Invalid table alias or column reference 'max_load': (possible column names are: ...` error

Comment: Try to do it with an inner join

Comment: with max_load as ( select max(loaddate) as loaddate from batch_table) 
    insert into delta_table 
    (select * from batch_table a  inner join max_load on a.loaddate= max_load.loaddate);

Answer (score 0):

Analytic function + filter will be more efficient than self-join or subquery with one more table scan to find max date:

```
insert into delta_table 
select col1, col2, ... coln --list columns here
from
(
select t.*, rank() over(order by loaddate desc) rnk
  from batch_table t
)s
where rnk=1;
```